# Requirements for getting the tile-cascade page transition to work in polymer

Tags: css, animation, polymer

I've been playing with this for a while, but can anyone explain what the requirements are to have the tile-cascade page transition to work in Polymer? When I take a look at the code for the transition, I see the following:

```
polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host(.tile-cascade) > * [tile-cascade] > div:nth-of-   type(2)'; }
:host(.tile-cascade) ::content > * /deep/ [tile-cascade] > div:nth-of-type(2) {
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host(.tile-cascade) > * [tile-cascade] > div:nth-of-type(3)'; }
:host(.tile-cascade) ::content > * /deep/ [tile-cascade] > div:nth-of-type(3) {
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
```

I believe this tells us what the markup should be made of (IE: It's looking for `div`s after the  element with the `tile-cascade` attribute, but I'm not sure if I'm missing other requirements. I've attached a screen shot of some of the code from Chrome dev tools in hopes that it will proved some context

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, there are three things that you need to do.

1. People often forget to include the reference for the `tile-cascade` animation. So make sure you have `<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-animated-pages/transitions/tile-cascade.html">` on top of your element.
2. You cannot apply the `tile-cascade` attribute to the direct child of your `core-animated-pages`. Apply it to the next level container.
3. Your `core-animated-pages` needs to include `tile-cascade` in the `transitions` attribute.

To demonstrate point 2 & 3, I have the following piece of code that works properly in my project.

```
<core-animated-pages selected="{{ $.tabs.selected }}" transitions="tile-cascade" notap fit>
    <section>
        <core-selector tile-cascade>
            <div class="portal-item">
                <div class="tile"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="portal-item">
                <div class="tile"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="portal-item">
                <div class="tile"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="portal-item">
                <div class="tile"></div>
            </div>
```

**Update**
 4. As *already mentioned in the OP*, each tile element needs to be wrapped by a `div`.

Say if you are using a `template` to iterate through the tiles, you will need to wrap whatever inside your template with a `div` otherwise the `tile-cascade` won't work (Interestingly, the `list-cascade` animation works without the need of the `div` wrapper). e.g.

```
<core-animated-pages transitions="cross-fade tile-cascade">
    <section>
        <div class="container" horizontal layout center-justified wrap cross-fade tile-cascade>
            <template repeat="{{item in hierarchyItems}}">
                <!-- you need this div here otherwise the tile-cascade animation doesn't work! -->
                <div>
                    <my-element></my-element>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </section>
```